# Python - Appending a new Dataframe column that is a function of two separate numerical columns

Tags: python, dataframe, mathematics

I have a dataset that gives me the geographic coordinates of residential properties.

My goal is to append a new column to this dataframe that shows the properties' distances to various prominent locations in the city. I plan on doing this by finding the difference in the latitude and longitude to give X and Y values, and using the pythagorean theorem to find the straight-line distance between the two locations.

How do I structure the code so that the new column is a pythagorean function of the differences between latitude and longitude?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the distance matrix to know the distance from one point to all other corresponding points.

Here is an example:

```py
def dist_PQ(P,Q):
    PP=P*P
    QQ=Q*Q
    PSquared_Sum = np.sum(PP,axis=1,keepdims=True)
    QSquared_Sum = np.sum(QQ,axis=1,keepdims=True)

    squared_distance = PSquared_Sum + QSquared_Sum.T - 2*np.dot(P,Q.T)

    return(squared_distance)
```

1. Use the above function to find distances between two sets of points say (`P` and `Q`)
2. Say P has 10 points the values are as `numpy` array `[[x11,y11],[x12,y12],[x13,y13]...]` and `Q` has 3 points as `[[x21,y21],[x22,y22],[x23,y23]]`.
3. pass `P` and `Q` to the `dist_PR` function to get the output as `(10,3)` matrix which gives the distances from all points in array `P` to all points of `Q`.

   - Now we can use the matrix of distance in our further calculation.
   - Suppose we want to find the place which is nearest from P1 (a point in `P`), we can simply find the minimum distance value in row number 1 of that distance matrix.

Comment: The euclidean distances could be computed more easily (and probably faster) with `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html